# Read request headers in ISAPI DLL

Tags: delphi, iis-10, delphi-10.4.2

I'm writing an ISAPI DLL, using Delphi 10.4.2 and IIS 10.

The configuration, the content, request-response, the debugging, all working fine.

But, I can't read the request 's custom Headers. The test request has come from Postman.

In `TWebModule1.WebModule1DefaultHandlerAction`, the request is inherited from `Web.Win.IsapiHTTP.TISAPIRequest`.

I'm using the `Web.Win.IsapiHTTP.TISAPIRequest.GetFieldByName()` method, as mentioned in the Embarcadero documentation.

I've added `<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />`  to the configuration file on the server side.

I feel that I'm missing something.

For example, this returns with empty content, but from the client-side I  sent it, every GetFieldByName returns with an empty string.

```
TWebModule1.WebModule1DefaultHandlerAction..
begin
  Response.statuscode := 200;
  response.Content := Request.GetFieldByName('ic_Something');
  Handled := true;
 end;
```

Comment: So, what exactly is stopping you from accessing custom headers? Please provide a [mcve] that is not working for you.

Comment: The getfieldbyname always returning empty string. For example, this code returns with an emty content: Response.statuscode := 200;
  response.Content := Request.GetFieldByName('ic_Something');
  Handled := true;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To read all the custom headers from the request in ISAPI you must specify ALL_RAW as the field name:

```
TWebModule1.WebModule1DefaultHandlerAction
var
  CustomHeaders: string;
begin
  CustomHeaders := Request.GetFieldByName('ALL_RAW');
end;
```

Comment: Thank you! For those who want to find all magic words search for this: IIS Server Variables.

Answer (score 2):

Per [ISAPI Server Variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/iis/6.0-sdk/ms524602(v=vs.90)), you need to use either `HEADER_<HeaderName>` or `HTTP_<HeaderName>` when retrieving a custom header:

| Variable | Description |
| --- | --- |
| HEADER_<HeaderName> IIS 5.1 and earlier: This server variable is not available. | The value stored in the header <HeaderName>. Any header other than those listed in this table must be preceded by "HEADER_" in order for the ServerVariables collection to retrieve its value. This is useful for retrieving custom headers. Note: Unlike HTTP_<HeaderName>, all characters in HEADER_<HeaderName> are interpreted as-is. For example, if you specify HEADER_MY_HEADER, the server searches for a request header named MY_HEADER. |
| HTTP_<HeaderName> | The value stored in the header <HeaderName>. Any header other than those listed in this table must be preceded by "HTTP_" in order for the ServerVariables collection to retrieve its value. This is useful for retrieving custom headers. Note: The server interprets any underscore (_) characters in <HeaderName> as dashes in the actual header. For example, if you specify HTTP_MY_HEADER, the server searches for a request header named MY-HEADER. |

For example:

```pascal
TWebModule1.WebModule1DefaultHandlerAction..
begin
  Response.statuscode := 200; 
  Response.Content := Request.GetFieldByName('HEADER_ic_Something');
  Handled := true; 
end;
```

**UPDATE:** apparently `GetFieldByName()` already looks for `HTTP_<HeaderName>` for you.  But per the above documentation, that will search for an HTTP header named `ic-Something`, whereas `HEADER_ic_Something` will search for `ic_Something` instead.  So use whichever one is more appropriate for your needs.

Comment: Delphi ISAPI layer already checks for fields starting with HTTP_ prefix. See TISAPIRequest.GetFieldByName source code

Comment: Yes, but `HTTP_ic_Something` will look for an HTTP header named `ic-Something`, whereas `HEADER_ic_Something` will look for `ic_Something` instead.

Comment: Thank you, Remy Lebeau! The HEADER_ic_something working well.